# TOR Anonymity Query

Tags: security

It is my understanding that TOR was actually created by the CIA, either directly or through some non-governmental entity.  I get this information from a reliable source that has a background with the CIA.  Given that you promote your site as being anonymous, I question how this be the case.  If the CIA created this to track terrorists or other persons of interest, how can it really be anonymous?

Answer (score 6):

Your "source" at the "CIA" (i.e. your "friend" with the tinfoil hat (i.e. you)) is wrong. It was created by the US Naval Research Lab, some of whom are still active within the community.

It's not secret information.

This is noted in the [Tor Project's FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#WhyCalledTor) and even in the [US Naval Research Lab's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Naval_Research_Laboratory#Electronic_warfare_and_information_security).